# Format a number with commas in two different fixed number of places

Tags: java, number-formatting

An example will best explain what I want - lets say, I have a number like this `34236536465.57`. I want to format it this way: `34,23,65,36,465.57`. Any JDK classes or third party libraries I can use for this other than doing it manually please? I have tried with `java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##,###.##")`, but the commas are coming after 3 digits only whereas I want the commas to come first after 3 digits and then after 2 digits onwards.

Comment: Thanks codelark. It seems like I don't have any other way but doing it manually.

Comment: @raatprohory May be you can do some string operations.

Comment: In fact, I was just testing ICU4J library's com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat class with the same pattern I used for java.text.DecimalFormat i.e. "#,##,###.##" and its formatting perfectly the way I wanted; that DecimalFormat of ICU4J has concepts like 'Primary Grouping Size' and 'Secondary Grouping Size' that exactly does this. Anyway, thanks for yours quick responses.

Comment: @raatprohory If you got the answer then put it as answer. May be in future someone can use it.

Comment: Thanks Smit. I did it.

Answer (score 1):

[com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html) class of ICU4J library can exactly do the same thing. And we can use the same pattern "#,##,###.##" as it is used in java.text.DecimalFormat to format the way exactly I wanted.